# JSON-LD context: Specifying (inherent) rdf:type of a property value

Tags: rdf, ontology, json-ld

I've created an owl ontology and want to create as simple transfer format possible. To do that, I'd like to include any context (vocab) information into json-ld context. Specifically, I'd like to specify (inherent) rdf:type of a value of a particular property.

So: I have this json:

```
{
  "@type": "Observation",
  "observedProperty": "temperature"
}
```

I'd like to create a context, so that the expanded form looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "@type": [
      "http://www.my.vocab.org/def/Observation"
    ],
    "http://www.my.vocab.org/def/observedProperty": [
      {
        "@id": "http://www.my.vocab.org/temperature",
        "@type": "http://www.my.vocab.org/def/Property"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expansion using this context:

```
"@context": {
    "@base": "http://www.my.vocab.org/",
    "@vocab": "def/",
    "property": "property/",
    "observedProperty": {
      "@type": "Property"
    }
  }
```

results in

```
...
   "@type": "http://www.my.vocab.org/def/Property",
   "@value": "temperature"
...
```

Expansion using

```
"@context": {
 ...
      "@type": "@id"
 ...
  }
```

obviously doesn't include the type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This has come up before, and type coercion doesn’t work that way. Take a look at the note in https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#type-coercion.

However, you can do this with framing.

Comment: That's a shame. Yes, framing looks quite powerful when it comes to shaping a graph into a json-ld document with fixed structure or even enriching it. 

But we're trying to develop an API for two sets of users: those who only want the simplest answer possible with least amount of data transferred (especially not interested in reading 1000x that observableProperty contains - what a surprise - Properties); and those who seek full semantic grounding, e.g. for automated processing.

Comment: While reading about json-ld, I was hoping we could build a simple interface that would publish core data and a context, that would help to interpret it, which would fully satisfy both categories. Now it looks like we'd have to build two interfaces or do some sort of compromise.